# How to add a value from html file with jinja2 into python array

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I have an array with some usernames in it.

```
users = ["foo", "bar"]
```

I am making a flask app. I want to reach that array put a value into that array.

```
{{ users.append(value) }}
```

But for that i need to get the value of an input element in my html file.

How do i do that?

Comment: any basic flask tutorial will cover getting data from a form. short version. In your view function  form = FormModel()   then  enteredfromhtml = form.field1.data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access the value like normal from your HTML file using POST and then manually append it to the array:

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "http://localhost:5000/" method = "post">
         <p>Enter Username:</p>
         <p><input type = "text" name = "nm" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "Enter" /></p>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

And then for your python code:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def append_to_array():
    users = ["foo", "bar"]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.form['nm'] # Search through the response for the value of 'nm'
        users.append(user)
```

Comment: i have an error that says 'request not defined\

Comment: If I am correct, request is a module in flask. So if you haven't imported it you should.

Comment: from flask import request